# Delete companies with the least number of flights

Tags: sql, mysql

I have solved the task of

> Delete the companies that made the least number of flights.

the visual table diagram is [here](https://drawsql.app/sql-academy-1/diagrams/airo?ref=embed). The exercise is [here](https://sql-academy.org/en/trainer/tasks/55)

This is my source code -it's "arrow antipattern" , what is more elegant solution?

the inner most counts num of flights and groups by company, this is used to compare and find the actual minimum, then just select company names and delete.

```
DELETE FROM company 
WHERE  name IN (SELECT name 
                FROM   (SELECT name 
                        FROM   trip 
                               INNER JOIN company 
                                       ON trip.company = company.id 
                        GROUP  BY name 
                        HAVING Count(trip.id) = (SELECT Min(kolv) AS mini  
                                                 FROM   (SELECT 
                                                Count(trip.id) AS kolv 
                                                         FROM   trip 
                                                INNER JOIN company 
                                                        ON trip.company 
                                                           = 
                                                           company.id 
                                                         GROUP  BY name 
                                                         ORDER  BY kolv)k)) o)
```

Comment: "companies" and "least"??  One company?  Several?  What cutoff do you want?

Comment: Delete from the table `company` only?  Won't leave dangling references in `trip`?  Maybe the task should be "Delete the company with the _least_ number of flights, plus all associated information."  But that would probably require 4 `DELETEs`, one per table.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RickJames According to [the linked exercise](https://sql-academy.org/en/trainer/tasks/55), deleting from `Company` only is sufficient, even it leaves dangling references. I verified this by checking @ERJAN's provided query, which returned "Right answer".

Comment: Why do you do `SELECT name FROM (SELECT name FROM trip`?

Answer (score 3):

If you can with MySQL 8.0, use the [`WITH` Common Table Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to simplify this query.

The idea is to extract out the nested queries into ones in the `WITH` statement before the main query and then use them just like tables in the main query.

Answer (score 3):

- If you look at the visual table diagram on the site you linked, for the `Company` table, the `id` is the primary key and therefore is guaranteed to be unique for each row in the table. `name`, on the other hand, is not guaranteed to be unique. So in your query, you should be grouping and deleting companies by their `id`, not by their `name`.
- Your query seems to be doing the work of counting the number of trips per company *twice* (once at the part `HAVING Count(trip.id)` and again at the part `Count(trip.id) AS kolv`) which is not necessary.
- As @Flavian and @RickJames have mentioned, refactoring your query to use Common Table Expressions will save it from the arrow anti-pattern, and make it much more readable.

An example refactor:

```sql
WITH TripsPerCompany AS (
    SELECT company, COUNT(id) AS num_trips FROM Trip GROUP BY company
)

,CompaniesWithTheFewestTrips AS (
    SELECT company
    FROM TripsPerCompany
    WHERE num_trips = (SELECT MIN(num_trips) FROM TripsPerCompany)
)

DELETE Company
FROM Company
JOIN CompaniesWithTheFewestTrips
ON Company.id = CompaniesWithTheFewestTrips.company;
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use the multi-table flavor of `DELETE`.  Why?  To avoid the "arrow".  And possibly the performance will be better.
- Avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )`; instead, try to use `JOIN` (or maybe `LEFT JOIN`).  The Optimizer has been notoriously poor at optimizing `IN (SELECT...)`.  I don't know whether it will do a good job here -- please add `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.
- Alternatively, do the task in steps -- Create a temp table with, say, the innermost pair of queries, then use that temp in the rest.  When doing this, be sure to explain what that temp table represents.  I make this suggestion because my head is still spinning from the "arrow".
- Use CTE, if available, instead of a temp table.  (There is a lot of overlap in the benefits/drawbacks between temp tables and CTEs.  CTEs are the "modern" answer, where applicable.)

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Could you please extend your suggestions with reasonings? Either by explaining yourself why should we prefer *x* over *y* Or by providing links about the related subjects.

Comment: @PeterCsala - Maybe my added text will help.  No, I don't happen to have any link to share.  Mostly I depend on 22 years of using MySQL.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Enjoy your time here.